# Hide/Show <p:inputText> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Is there any option to set  flag to true and hide `<p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.value}" />` on change?

JSF code below

```
<h:form>
      <p:selectOneMenu style="width:150px" id="id" onchange="onCall()">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="Other"></f:selectItem>
       </p:selectOneMenu>
       <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="flag"/>
       <p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.value}/>
 </h:form>
```

Please give me an idea to solve my issue

Comment: You're asking how to do something with jQuery (client-side) but you're only showing server-side code.  Your client-side code will need to operate on the client-side output, separate from what you've shown.

Comment: No Just I want to validate in client side itself..

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to do?  jQuery can not modify a `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="flag"/>` but it can modify the client-side code generated by that.  Similarly, it can't hide `<p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.value}/>` but it can hide the client-side code generated by that.  In your jQuery code you need to target the client-side elements.  At that point, calling `.hide()` or `.val()` on those elements will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two ways to achieve this, jQuery or Normal JSF.

---

**JSF**

---

***Bean***

```
private Boolean renderInputText;

public void setRenderInputText(Boolean renderInputText) {
    this.renderInputText = renderInputText
}

public Boolean getRenderInputText() {
   return renderInputText;
}
```

***xhtml***

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="flag" value="{bean.renderInputText}" >.
   <p:ajax update="inputPanel" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<h:panelGroup id="inputPanel">
    <p:inputText rendered="{bean.renderInputText}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

---

**jQuery**

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <!-- This can be located either in the facelet or in external js file-->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            PF('selectWV').jq.change(function() {
                if (PF('selectWV').isChecked()) {
                    PF('buttonWV').jq.show();
                } else {
                    PF('buttonWV').jq.hide();
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">
                    Accept Terms: <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
            widgetVar="selectWV" />
        <p:commandButton value="Register" widgetVar="buttonWV"
            style="display: none" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

---

A small working example (jQuery version) can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/checkBoxesJQuery/terms.xhtml), two main files [terms.xhtml](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/checkBoxesJQuery/terms.xhtml) and [terms.js](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/js/terms.js)

And an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/checkBoxesJQuery/terms.xhtml).

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 1):

**JSF / Server-side solution:**

If you don't want to display a JSF component, use the `rendered` attribute. E.g.

```
<p:inputText id="name" ... rendered="#{myBean.displayed}" />
```

And set the `displayed` boolean to false if you want to hide it. This will occur server side.

**JavaScript / client-side solution:**

You can also use JavaScript code, this solution would have almost nothing to do with JSF or PrimeFaces:

*JavaScript function*:

```
function hideNameInput() {
    $('[id="#{p:component('name')}"]').hide();
}
```

`#{p:component('name')}` will return the HTML identifier of the input.

Comment: Hide component working and same time I want change checkbox flag status to true

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and a boolean value in your bean (like flag) to do this

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:selectOneMenu style="width:150px" id="id" onchange="onCall()">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="Other"></f:selectItem>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="flag" value="#{mybean.flag}" update="mainForm"/>
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.value}" rendered="#{mybean.flag}"/>
</h:form>
```

Edit : forgot to reload the view to show / hide after the change of value

Regards

Comment: he is asking for a client side solution.

Comment: Is there anyway do it throw client level without using server code

Comment: Why do you want to do it on the client side ?

Comment: The OP is asking for doing it at client side..

Comment: @XtremeBiker It really helped saying a second time, thx

Comment: Separating javascript from HTML is one of the basics in code/markup organization and role distribution